# EJB/JPA batch process exception management

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, batch-file, ejb

Here is my problem.
I work on a synchronization batch using 2 EJB/JPA/Hibernate modules.

The first module reads information in the database A and detects changes.
Once detected, modified items are sent to the second module through JMS.

The second module reads the message and iterates through the modified items and updates information in the database B.

Once the update process is finished, a message containing the ID of the items successfully updated is sent to the first module who flags in the database A the successfully updated items.

**All the process works but I don't know how to manage exception that could occur during the persistence process using the container managed EntityManager**.

If I wasn't working with a container managed EntityManager I would open a new transaction for each insert and commit it or rollback it depending if any exception occurred.

I need to know when an exception occurred in order not to add the id of the item being currently processed, and causing an exception, in the list with the id of the items successfully updated. Also, if I'm processing 10 items and that the first one in the list creates an exception I need to continue with the other 9 items.

I thought that using @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) in front of the persistent methods would solve my issue but it didn't.

**Is there a way to do what I need to do using a container managed EntityManager?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By using @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN) for the definition of the class. I was able to manage the transaction by myself.

```
@Stateless

@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyBean implements MyBeanInterface{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    @Override
    public List<String> updateItems(List<Items> items) {
        List<String> itemsId=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Item item : items){
            try{
                userTransaction.begin();
                doMyStuff(...);
                userTransaction.commit();
                itemsId.add(item.getId());
            }catch(Exception e){
                try {
                    userTransaction.rollback();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();                       
                } catch (SystemException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return itemsId;
    }
}
```

It's working but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do it?
I mean without using explicit beginTransaction, commitTransaction and rollbackTransaction.
For example by using annotations around the methods call by doMyStuff():

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create new transaction each time. whenever you want to rollback a transaction you can choose to rollback the transaction three levels.1) [Use SetRollbackOnly](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html) 2) [Mark Exception with ApplicationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html) 3)Throw Runtime (Should not be used)